# Model parameter takes no effect in {{render}} helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js

The second parameter should be model, but it take no effects in my example:

template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="guestlist">
  {{#each}}
  <div class="visitor-li">
         <div class="user-name">{{name}}</div>
         <div class="clear"></div>
  </div>
  {{/each}}     
</script><!-- end with x-handlebars -->
```

javascript:

```
window.WorkBench = Ember.Application.create({});
WorkBench.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();  

WorkBench.Guestlist = DS.Model.extend({ 
    name: DS.attr("string") 
});

WorkBench.Guestlist.FIXTURES = [
  { id: 1, name: 'aaa' },
  { id: 2,  name: 'bbb' },
  { id: 3,  name: 'ccc' }
];
WorkBench.GuestlistController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({});
```

html

```
<div id="con_taba_1">
    {{render "guestlist" guestlist}}
</div>
```

A list should be displayed, but no go.I want know why, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter needs to actually exist in the context where you're using it.  You are passing in an undefined property.

A way to prove this is to just log out `guestlist` right there

```
<div id="con_taba_1">
    {{log guestlist}}
    {{render "guestlist" guestlist}}
</div>
```

The `guestlist` property needs to exist in the scope of where you are using the render statement, that context can be seen by logging `this`  (I'd tell you, but you've left out that information).

```
<div id="con_taba_1">
    {{log this}}
    {{log guestlist}}
    {{render "guestlist" guestlist}}
</div>
```

generally the model information is provided from the `model` hook in the `route` related to the context mentioned above.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    return { bar:'baz'};
  }
});
```

In the `foo` template you could do {{log bar}} and you would see `baz`.

Here's a playground for you for setting it up, [http://Emberjs.jsbin.com](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! But I use the model

Comment: Will you show your route that's backing the template with the render

Comment: Sorry for incomplete comment, I mean the model is different from model of route, so I use {{render}} to specify one, I do not know how to use this way.

Comment: gotcha, the property must exist on the controller backing that template.  If you want you can add a computed property, named `guestlist`, in that controller that returns the model necessary for that template you are attempting to render.

Comment: I added a property in applicationController as: guestlist: (function(){return this.get('store').find('guestlist');}).property(), then it works! Thanks!